# CollapsingToolbarLayout: Keep Toolbar but hide TabLayout with quick return

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-tablayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want the Toolbar to always be visible and have the TabLayout get scrolled away and quick return but this combination seems impossible.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <CollapsingToolbarLayout layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <TabLayout/>
            <Toolbar layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </AppBarLayout>
    <ViewPager/>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

This makes my Toolbar not scroll away, but it makes the TabLayout only return when scrolled to the top of the list.

Changing to `scroll|enterAlways`on the CollapsingToolbarlayout makes the Toolbar scroll away too.

Comment: Try adding `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` to the `Toolbar` and add `scroll|enterAlways` to the CollapsingToolbarLayout. Remove `layout_scrollFlags` from CollapsingToolbarLayout

Comment: If I remove `layout_scrollFlags` from `CollapsingToolbarLayout` nothing reacts to scrolling. Adding `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` did not help. Setting `scroll|enterAlways` on the CollapsingToolbarLayout makes the Toolbar scroll away.

Comment: Sorry i meant remove `layout_scrollFlags` from CollapsingToolbarLayout(CTL henceforth) children...the children but not the CTL itself, but that name is tooo long, I forgot what i was writing on the way. But keep `scroll|exitUntilCollapsed` on the CTL

Comment: `exitUntilCollapsed` does not give me quick return stuff. Changing that one to `enterAlways` makes the Toolbar go away. I'm going insane.

Edit: I changed my question a bit.

Answer (score 2):

A solution was to have the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` have these scroll flags.

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlways"
```

But the shadow is missing..

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why hide the tabs but show the toolbar? The opposite is more appropriate/intuitive imo...

Comment: The toolbar is showing info about the recyclerview inside the viewpager. It does make sense in this case.